# web2py configurations per environment does not work with scheduler / scripts

Tags: python, web2py

I have been using the recommended method for setting up DB connections per environment in web2py:

```
settings = dict()
if request.env.http_host == 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
     settings['development']=True
else:
     settings['development']=False
if settings['development']:
     db = DAL('sqlite://....')
else:
     db = DAL('mysql://....')
```

When using the scheduler in the non-development environment the db connections fail as it is using the port 8000 config.

Similarly when attempting to run a script I get the same errors.  This is my last attempt:

```
python web2py.py -S app -M -N -R -L options.py -P 443 applications/testscript.py

"Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)"�
```

Is there a recommended way to inject a config per environment that will apply outside of web access?

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily insert the following on a page:

```
{{=response.toolbar()}}
```

Then on both development and production, click the "request" button and inspect the values in `request.env` to identify things that differ between the two environments. Some likely candidates are "server_signature", "server_software", and "web2py_path".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same concern and I first though of `request.env.server_name`.
But:

- this variable does not exist when starting the scheduler
- it could be replaced by `request.env.cmd_options.server_name` but first, this one does not exist for the server and second, after its startup, the scheduler does not find it any more...

Then I found this Q/A and tried to solve it following Anthony's advice:

- "server_signature" does not exist when starting up the scheduler
- "server_software" does not exist when starting up the scheduler

Finally, "web2py_path" does the job even if for me, testing against a full installation path is not really a 'clean' solution...

```py
if request.env.web2py_path == '/your/path/on/server/to/web2py'
    settings['development']=False
else:
    settings['development']=True
```

Now it should work, but I fell into this one : [Can not run the web2py scheduler using postgresql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28169849/can-not-run-the-web2py-scheduler-using-postgresql-database)