# Can not run the web2py scheduler using postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, web2py, scheduler

I can run the scheduler using sqlite database, but I will got the error when I change to using postgres database.

Code (task.py):

```
def AutoRemoveCacheData():
    return 'OK'

from gluon.scheduler import Scheduler
scheduler = Scheduler(db,dict(AutoRemoveCacheData=AutoRemoveCacheData),migrate=True)
```

Error message:

```
root@ip-123-45-67-321:/var/www/web2py# python web2py.py -K ScheduleApp
web2py Web Framework
Created by Massimo Di Pierro, Copyright 2007-2015
Version 2.9.11-stable+timestamp.2014.09.15.23.35.11
Database drivers available: SQLite(sqlite3), MySQL(pymysql), PostgreSQL(pg8000), IMAP(imaplib)
starting single-scheduler for "ScheduleApp"...
ERROR:web2py.scheduler.ip-123-45-67-321#1388:Error retrieving status
ERROR:web2py.scheduler.ip-123-45-67-321#1388:Error retrieving status
ERROR:web2py.scheduler.ip-123-45-67-321#1388:Error retrieving status
```

Anybody know how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having the same error.

- Development environment: windows version of web2py w/ included web server and sqlite
- Production environment: web2py tied to Apache on Linux web server and PostgreSQL.

To get the actual error cause, I tweaked `gluon/scheduler.py`. After removing the guilty try/except of Scheduler.send_heartbeat() I got the following error: `NotSupportedError: type oid 114 not mapped to py type`

Googling around with this error I found [that discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py/BV63YohZ6pQ) where Niphlod says: "*The problem comes from pg8000 not supporting the json type. **Use psycopg2 instead**.*"

So, let's try with this Python module...

Comment: Thanks Frédéric!
`sudo apt-get install psycopg2`